# How to run Eclipse Mars using a newer version of GTK+ on Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, eclipse, gtk3

Linux Mint 17.x contains GTK+ 3.10.8, which is very old.  So old, that Eclipse Mars has some serious bugs when running with it (the most serious one is the file names missing in the Git commit dialog https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=480032).

Is there any way to compile + install a newer version of GTK+ on Linux Mint 17?  I tried manually installing the packages from Ubuntu Vivid, but that opens up a dependency hell.

Alternatively, can I install a newer version of GTK+ in some other directory, and start Eclipse so that it uses that version instead?

Comment: As you didn't specify what bugs you experience, we cannot reproduce it. Simply putting a link is not acceptable. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by adding the following two lines to the `eclipse.ini` (simply put it under one of the other `--launcher` options):

```
--launcher.GTK_version
2
```

This will tell eclipse to use GTK2 which is not affected by the bug. I added two images for reference.

Before:
[image: Before]

After:
[image: After]

Comment: Great, that fixed the issue.  Another bug still remains (double-clicking a file in the commit dialog opens the difference dialog incorrectly, resizing the window corrects the view) but that's less critical.

Comment: Unfortunately, this crashes eclipse in many situations, like many others have stated in eclipse bug reports.